How to pass a list of strings as a python sys.argv in a script, when the script command must be executed from a string
Suppose you have a script.py that takes various input arguments, so you can run it by a command line like:
python script.py arg1 arg2

sys.argv can be used inside script.py to read those arguments:
sys.argv[1] # gives you str(arg1)
sys.argv[2] # gives you str(arg2)

Example of script.py :
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv[2])
print(eval(sys.argv[2]))
print(type(eval(sys.argv[2])))

Suppose that the desired content of arg2 is a list of strings, like ["x?47", "b-12", "k:4"].
If you are writing the command manually, you can of course do:
python script.py 156 '["x?47", "b-12", "k:4"]'

By single-quoting outside the list, there is no problem.
You get as output:
156
["x?47", "b-12", "k:4"]
['x?47', 'b-12', 'k:4']
<class 'list'>

The last two lines indicate that string sys.argv[2] has been correctly interpreted as a list of strings, as desired. One could do further work with those strings.
However, what if you must create the above command itself as a string cmd and execute it programmatically, e.g. by os.system(cmd)?
I tried several different approaches, escaping by '', double quoting, etc., but none of them worked.
It seems that cmd just cannot contain the two different types of quotes, or at least, not in a format that is then correctly processed by code like os.system().
Invariably, you end up with a cmd like:
python script.py 156 ["x?47", "b-12", "k:4"]

which obviously does not work:
156
[x?47,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/code/PersonalFolders/GT/script.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(eval(sys.argv[2]))
  File "<string>", line 1
    [x?47,
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I discussed this with some colleagues, who advised to either change the whole code, from using sys.argv to using argparse (probably best solution in the long term, but also more demanding to implement), or to pass the list as a single string containing only the strings that are inside the list, separated by commas or some other suitable character that I can split on.
So in this case I would pass "x?47,b-12,k:4" and then do sys.argv[2].split(',').
I just wanted to understand from this expert community if it is really wrong to want to pass a list of strings as an argument in this situation, or if we missed something that would resolve the issue without having to change the script.

EDIT : trying out John Gordon's solution

So this solution works for os.system(), which I mentioned as an example.
On retry, it actually also works with the original job launcher I am using, namely Domino job_start (see https://github.com/dominodatalab/python-domino/blob/master/domino/domino.py).

If you must use os.system the escaping can become complicated (there may be even multiple edge cases). If you can use subprocess.run it is easy: subprocess.run(['python', 'script.py', '156', repr(["x?47", "b-12", "k:4"])]) as run should care about escaping automatically if needed and by default doesn't use a shell (which would mangle the arguments additionally).

Quibble about "should care about escaping automatically": With shell=False, no escaping (other than that implicitly performed by repr) needs to be done at all, except on Windows; on UNIXy systems the native syscall to ask the OS to run a command takes a list of C strings and passes them precisely as they are to the child.

In general, do not use os.system as you open yourself up to vulnerabilities especially with user-provided arguments, but instead prefer subprocess.run.

I actually do not use os.system. I use a Domino job_start. And I have no choice, I must do it that way. I mentioned os.system here for simplicity and because it was what I tried when job_start did not work properly, thinking that it could be unrelated to the cmd. I am now quite sure that it is related to the cmd. Not sure what vulnerabilities are possible here, but I am told by my expert colleagues that we work in a very safe and controlled environment. There are no random users running these commands, it's always us or our processes.


It seems that cmd just cannot contain the two different types of quotes

Nonsense.  Of course it can.
There are lots of different ways to do it.  The easiest is probably to use triple-quoting:
cmd = """python script.py 156 '["x?47", "b-12", "k:4"]'"""
os.system(cmd)


This is true, but an OP that doesn't know what they're doing is likely to generate code with shell injection vulnerabilities going down this path. Much safer to teach shlex.quote() or subprocess.Popen(..., shell=False).

Thanks, I tried the triple quote trick, and it put ' instead of ' (by itself, i.e. the string contained the escape backslash even though I had never used it). I will try again tomorrow, because I did not do 100% exactly what you suggested here. If it works, fine by me. I confirm that I only partly :) know what I am doing when it comes to python, hence my asking for advice here. Please note my use of a dubitative form ('it seems that'), because if I knew how this works, I wouldn't need to ask. So no need to call what I wrote 'nonsense'.

@user6376297 it put ' instead of ' No, it didn't.  You misinterpreted what you saw.  If you print() the string, you will see there are no backslashes.

Yes, I got the point that ' is translated to ' by print commands. What I did not know was whether it would also be translated that way by stuff like os.system(). I was in doubt about that because when I used Domino job_start, the ' remained '. To leave no stone unturned, I should have tried os.system(), too, because indeed, you are correct, it works there. I will post in my OP, and I will accept your answer, as you answered my question. Shame that Domino job_start does not work. BTW I did not downvote you, and I don't understand why one would, as your solution works.

Actually, no, the triple quoted cmd now works even with Domino job_start... not sure why it did not when I tried it yesterday. Anyway, thanks again for pointing this solution out, I hope it is useful to other people who may encounter the same issue.

As Charles mentioned, executing the script via shell can cause security vulnerabilities in your program.
Using the shlex package will allow you to do what you want to in a safer way.
import os
import shlex

arg1 = 156
arg2 = str(["x?47", "b-12", "k:4"])

cmd = f"python script.py {arg1} {shlex.quote(arg2_str)}"

os.system(cmd)

The shlex.quote() command found here will convert the string version of your array into a version that will work on UNIX shell environments.

shlex.quote is not for use with Windows shells.  It is not safe to do so and explicitly written in the documentation.

@MaximilianBurszley, ...does the question state that the OP is targeting Windows? I'm missing it if so.

For this specific piece of work, I am not using Windows.
